# Picklist Choice Set - Fields does not appear for New Object

Tags: visual-workflow, picklist, visual-flows

I created a new Object and new fields. I am building a Screen flow. I am trying to create a Picklist Choice Set type resource. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_resources_picklistchoice.htm&type=5

[image]

I am unable to see the fields under the selected object. I tried adding the API name manually but it gave an error. I checked whether I can select a field from a diff object and it appeared.

Any idea if this only happens to a new Object? Do I need to enable anything for the new object fields to be accessible from FLOW?

Comment: Definitely check that the object/field were given visibility to profiles as they're all disabled by default on new object creation. Otherwise, a refresh of the page might do the trick if you just literally created it. Not to mention making sure you're actually looking for a picklist (and not a multi-picklist field).

Comment: That's right! Missing profile permissions. If you put it as an answer I will accept iit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not showing up after creation, the likely scenario is you just need to refresh the Flow Builder page if you had it opened before you created the object/field.

If that doesn't solve the issue, you could double check the object/field is visible to a profile.

1. Give permission to profile for the new object

   On "New Custom Object" page, there's the following note in yellow

> Permissions for this object are disabled for all profiles by default.

[image]

2. Check that the picklist field is visible/accessible to profiles.
3. Make sure you select the appropriate data type (picklist vs. multi-picklist)